# how to write test code for pdfjs using mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, pdf.js, jsdom

While using mocha and chai to test my `pdfloader` (which uses `pdfjs`) it does not enter the `getDocument()` function.

```js
  pdfjsLib.getDocument(
    'http://localhost:8080/document.pdf',
    window.document,
    window
  ).promise.then(function (data) {
          pdfDoc = data;
          pdfDoc.getPage(1).then (handlePages);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
      });
}
```

If you check out this [repository](https://github.com/ousmorez/pdfLoader) on github and do as it says in the readme file, then run the `npm run test` command, you'll notice that the code doesn't run `getDocument()` and because of that the pdf file can't be load in test environment in jsdom.

repo: https://github.com/ousmorez/pdfLoader

`getDocument()` is executed in normal usage mode and while you are running the program, it just doesn't work in the test process.

I can't find the answer, what can I do?

Comment: Where does the `pdfjsLib` come from? Show minimal, complete code

Comment: If you check out my repo, complete code is there but at first line of test.js file code below is entered:
`const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist');` 

 and to use it in app,js file i use code below in index.js

`<script src="node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>`